# Install Facebook app on my tester's account

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an iOS app that should allow Facebook login, and I'm trying to get a list of my friends who have the FB app installed.

Since I don't have any real friends using this app I created an additional account, and set it in my FB app as a "Tester." So far so good.

But now I'm using the `FBFriendPickerViewController` to get a list of my friends who have the app installed, and my Tester account isn't showing. This is the code I'm using:

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *fbFriendsController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
fbFriendsController.delegate = self;
NSSet *fields = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"installed", nil];
fbFriendsController.fieldsForRequest = fields;
[fbFriendsController clearSelection];
[fbFriendsController loadData];
[self presentViewController:fbFriendsController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The TableView comes up empty - and stays empty even after the data is loaded and a list of my friends is printed out in the consol vie the `(BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user` delegate method.

I think my code is correct, and maybe the setup is lacking? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you logged into your app with your test account?

Comment: Actually, no. I'm not even sure how to find it from my test account. I mean, I'm logging into my iOS app using my own FB account.

Answer (score 0):

You, as a real Facebook user, cannot see the test user accounts as you're not friends. The best way to proceed is as follows:

1. Go to your [Facebook app settings](http://developers.facebook.com/apps/).
2. Go to **Developer Roles** by clicking the **Edit Roles** link at the bottom right and you'll see your Test Users at the bottom.
3. Click the **Modify** click on the right. Here, you'll see the email address of the temporary test users.
4. Make a couple of accounts and click the Make Friends button. Click the **See More** link on the right, and then the **Edit** link and you can set a password for each user.
5. If your test device has the Facebook app installed, log into the Facebook app using one of the test accounts, and then run your app and sign in via Facebook. This test user will then be flagged as having installed your app.
6. Do the same with another of your test accounts. Now you should see your first test account in the picker view.

Comment: Actually I am already friends with my Tester but I'm still not seeing him. Shouldn't I be able to go to my test account, find my FB app, and install it?

Comment: So I logged into the app as my test account through the simulator, and now back on my device, as my real account, I can see that the tester is installed. This makes sense, but now I'm not sure what's the point of setting a Tester to my FB app.

Comment: If you're Facebook app is in sandbox mode, only the Administrators, Developers, and Testers, and Test Users can use it.